# Fail to import JSON typescript

Tags: json, typescript, mocking

I need to use mock json to test my front-end render.

```
import MOCK_FAQ from '../../mocks/FAQ.json';
```

When I try to import the file i got this exception:

```
Cannot find module '../../mocks/FAQ.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extensionts(2732)
```

But I'm ready using this property on my tsconfig file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"allowJs": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"jsx": "react",
"lib": [
  "dom",
  "es6"
],
"moduleResolution": "node",
"noEmit": true,
"strict": true,
"target": "esnext"
  },
 "exclude": [
"node_modules",
"babel.config.js",
"metro.config.js",
"jest.config.js"
 ]
}
```

Someone can helps? o/

Comment: set `"traceResolution": true` and search the output for  `../../mocks/FAQ.json`

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you set `"resolveJsonModule": true`. and save `tsconfig.json` like:

```
import * as MOCK_FAQ from '../../mocks/FAQ.json';
```

Or you can try another way to import json file as below:

```
const MOCK_FAQ = require('../../mocks/FAQ.json');
```